# Bind concrete object to IOptions interface in dotnet

Tags: c#, .net-core, dependency-injection, configuration

I want to register an IOptions implementation having an object with needed data .
Having a IConfiguration with such data I can easily do this like this: (assuming IConfiguration has everything inside)

```
.ConfigureServices((context, services) =>
{
    services.AddOptions<SmtpConfig>().BindConfiguration(nameof(SmtpConfig));
})
```

No how can I do the same with concrete data in place? Something like this:

```
services.AddOptions<SmtpConfig>().Bind(myData);
```

or

```
services.AddOptions<SmtpConfig>().Bind(new SmtpConfig() { ... });
```

Comment: Are you saying that `mydata` already has some of its properties set and you want the options binding to fill-in the others?

Comment: I want to register `myData` to request it later through DI using `IOptions` pattern

Answer (score 2):

You can try using this pattern:

```
services.AddSingleton(serviceProvider =>
{
    return Options.Create(myData);
});
```

and then use it for DI like this:

```
private readonly SmtpConfig _smtpConfig;

public MailService(IOptions<SmtpConfig> smtpConfig)
{
    _smtpConfig = smtpConfig.Value;
}
```

I know that this isn't the prettiest way but it works.

Answer (score 1):

To register an `IOptions` implementation using a concrete object, you can use the `Configure` method of the `IServiceCollection` interface, like this:

```
var myData = new SmtpConfig() { ... };
services.Configure<SmtpConfig>(options => options = myData);
```

This will register the `SmtpConfig` object as the implementation of the `IOptions<SmtpConfig>` interface, so that it can be injected into other classes via constructor injection.

Alternatively, if you want to register the `SmtpConfig` object as a singleton, you can use the `AddSingleton` method of the `IServiceCollection` interface, like this:

```
var myData = new SmtpConfig() { ... };
services.AddSingleton<SmtpConfig>(myData);
```

This will ensure that the same instance of the `SmtpConfig` object is used throughout the application.

Comment: >services.Configure<SmtpConfig>(options => options = myData);
doesn't work for me